# Oracle - Sum function and flag column update

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2_LINES (NAMES VARCHAR2(12), LINE_NO NUMBER, UNITS NUMBER(18,4), CODE VARCHAR2(4));

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',1,1,'101');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',2,1,'202');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',3,1,'180');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',4,2,'300');

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('RYAN',1,2,'180');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('RYAN',2,1,'180');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('RYAN',3,1,'500');

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('OLAN',1,1,'301');

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('TONY',1,1,'201');
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE TABLE4_CODES (CD_NM VARCHAR2(12), B_CODE VARCHAR2(4), E_CODE VARCHAR2(4));

INSERT INTO TABLE4_CODES VALUES ('CODELIST','100','101');
INSERT INTO TABLE4_CODES VALUES ('CODELIST','180','180');
INSERT INTO TABLE4_CODES VALUES ('CODELIST','200','219');

INSERT INTO TABLE4_CODES VALUES ('EXCODELIST','180','180');
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE RESULT1 (NAMES VARCHAR2(12), TOT_UNITS NUMBER, FLAG VARCHAR2(2));
COMMIT;
```

- Case 1: For person `JOHN`, We have eligible codes i.e. `101`,`202`,`180` (these codes present in `TABLE4_CODES` table of CD_NM `CODELIST`). It has other eligible codes along with 180 so `SUM(UNITS)` is `3` and `FLAG` should be populated as `O`
- Case 2: For person `RYAN`, We have only 1 eligible code i.e. `180` only (this code present in `TABLE4_CODES` table of CD_NM `EXCODELIST`...Need to look into CD_NM = `EXCODELIST` instead of `CODELIST`), so `SUM(UNITS)` is `3` and `FLAG` should be populated as `N`
- Case 3: For person `OLAN`, we don't have eligible codes so need to do anything.
- Case 4: For person `TONY`, we have eligible code `201` but we don't have 180 so (this code present in `TABLE4_CODES` table of `CD_NM` = `CODELIST`), so `SUM(UNITS)` is `1` and `FLAG` should be populated as `N`

---

- If particular person has multiple eligible codes along with `180`, we need to look into `TABLE4_CODES` table of CD_NM `CODELIST` before proceeding for sum calculation. Ex: `JOHN`
- If particular person has single/multiple eligible codes with don't have `180`, we need to look into `TABLE4_CODES` table of CD_NM `CODELIST` before proceeding for sum calculation Ex: `TONY`
- If particular person has only 1 eligible code i.e. `180`, we need to look into `TABLE4_CODES` table of CD_NM `EXCODELIST` before proceeding for sum calculation.  Ex: `RYAN`

Output to be expected in `RESULT1` table using `TABLE2_LINES` and `TABLE4_CODES`:

```
NAMES    TOT_UNITS       FLAG
-----------------------------
JOHN      3               O
RYAN      3               N 
TONY      1               O
```

Comment: Do we need to use RANK or ROW_NUMBER concept here? I tried but I am not getting expected result

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand the rules. What is the difference between B_CODE and E_CODE in TABLE4_CODES? Then, you said (for JOHN) "We have eligible codes i.e. 101,202,180 (these codes present in TABLE4_CODES table of CD_NM CODELIST)", but - there's no code 202 in TABLE4_CODES at all. The same goes for TONY whose code = 201, and there's no such a value in TABLE4_CODES. For me, it is difficult to follow your explanation because I can't see values you're specifying.

Comment: value '202' lies between '200' and '219' in TABLE4_CODES of CD_NM 'CODELIST'

Comment: B_CODE means starting code and E_CODE means ending code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood it. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  t180 as
  3    -- does NAME have code = 180? If so, return 1; else, return 0
  4    (select t2.names,
  5       max(case when t2.code = 180 then 1 else 0 end) as f180
  6     from table2_lines t2
  7     group by t2.names
  8    ),
  9  eligible as
 10    -- number of eligible rows per NAME
 11    (select t2.names,
 12       count(distinct t2.code) cnt_eligible
 13     from table2_lines t2 join table4_codes t4 on t2.code
 14          between t4.b_code and t4.e_code
 15     group by t2.names
 16    ),
 17  total_rows as
 18    -- gotal number of rows per NAME
 19    (select t2.names,
 20       count(*) cnt_total
 21     from table2_lines t2
 22     group by t2.names
 23    )
 24  -- apply rules (within the CASE expression) to return desired result
 25  select distinct
 26    t2.names,
 27    case when e.cnt_eligible = 1  and f.f180 = 1 then t.cnt_total -- Ryan, N
 28         when e.cnt_eligible >= 1 and f.f180 = 0 then e.cnt_eligible -- Tony, O
 29         when e.cnt_eligible >= 1 and f.f180 = 1 then e.cnt_eligible -- John, O
 30    end tot_units,
 31    --
 32    case when e.cnt_eligible = 1  and f.f180 = 1 then 'N' -- Ryan, N
 33         when e.cnt_eligible >= 1 and f.f180 = 0 then 'O' -- Tony, O
 34         when e.cnt_eligible >= 1 and f.f180 = 1 then 'O' -- John, O
 35    end flag
 36  from table2_lines t2 join t180 f on f.names = t2.names
 37  join eligible e on e.names = t2.names
 38  join total_rows t on t.names = t2.names;
```

Result:

```
NAMES         TOT_UNITS FLAG
------------ ---------- ----
JOHN                  3 O
RYAN                  3 N
TONY                  1 O

SQL>
```